# Bad Access Error When Uploading Data

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Im trying to get my app to use AFNetworking and its coming up with an error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x170730058) on the line where NSDictinary is.

I don't know where I'm going wrong...

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theimage.image, 1.0);

NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: thetext.text, @"text",time, @"time", eventId.text, @"eventId",youtubelink, @"youtubelink", (spoiler.isOn?"Y":"N"), @"spoiler", nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"http://....../upload.php" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" fileName:@"image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} error:nil];
```

Comment: You forgot the `@` on your "Y" and "N"`

Answer (score 0):

@ needed to be added at the Y and N at the end of the code

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11322146)

Comment: @SK he is the author... Agreed it isn't the best answer in the world, but it provides closure to the question and therefore is ultimately useful.